# LWC not calling apex with @wire

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have worked with LWC a little, and am working on some code that was written by someone else. The @wire was working and then quit. I am not sure why and I can't figure out what I have that is wrong. The debug log doesn't show the apex method getRelatedShipToList being called at all. Any help would be appreciated.

.html

```
<!-- sldsValidatorIgnore -->
<template>
    <template if:true={showModal}>
        <section
            role="dialog"
            tabindex="-1"
            aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01"
            aria-modal="true"
            aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1"
            class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open"
        >
            <!-- <div class="slds-modal__content slds-var-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1" > -->
            <div class="modalBox__container">
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <lightning-button-icon
                        class="slds-modal__close"
                        title="Close"
                        icon-name="utility:close"
                        icon-class="slds-button_icon-inverse"
                        onclick={handleDialogClose}
                    ></lightning-button-icon>

                        <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate header-slot" >
                            <slot name="header">
                                Manage Account Ownership
                            </slot>
                        </h2>

                    <p class="slds-var-m-top_x-small modal-hidden">
                        <slot name="tagline" onslotchange={handleSlotTaglineChange} >
                        <!-- <slot name="tagline" > -->
                            Related Ship-To Record Owners
                        </slot>
                    </p>
                </header>
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-var-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1" >
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-text-align_center">
                            First pick the user you want the owners changed to. You can use one of the current ship to owners or you can lookup a user.<br/>
                            Second select the accounts you want updated.<br />
                            Third click Update Ownership.
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 headerRow">
                            Change Customer Owner To:
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2 slds-text-align_center" style="padding-right:10px;">
                            Current Ship To Owners
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2 slds-text-align_center" style="padding-left:10px;">
                            Lookup Owner
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2" style="padding-right:10px;">
                            <lightning-datatable
                                class='shipToOwnerTbl'
                                key-field="OwnerId"
                                data={shipToOwnerUniqueList}
                                columns={shipToOwners}
                                onrowselection={handleRowSelection}
                                max-row-selection=1
                                hide-table-header
                            ></lightning-datatable>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2" style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name='Account'>
                                <lightning-input-field
                                    field-name='User__c'
                                    onchange={handleChange}
                                    variant="label-hidden"
                                    value={lookupValue}
                                    class="shipToOwnerLkup"
                                ></lightning-input-field>
                            </lightning-record-edit-form>
                        </div>

                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-text-align_center tableHeaderRow slds-var-m-top_medium">
                            Customer Account
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
                            <lightning-datatable 
                                key-field="id" 
                                data={customerAccountlist} 
                                columns={customerColumns}
                                class="customerAccountTable"
                            ></lightning-datatable>
                        </div>

                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-text-align_center tableHeaderRow slds-var-m-top_medium">
                            Ship To Accounts
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
                            <!-- <template if:false={shipToOwnerUniqueList}>
                                <p class="slds-var-m-top_x-small modal-hidden">
                                    <slot name="tagline">
                                        This Account Does Not Have Any Related Ship-To Records
                                    </slot>
                                </p>
                            </template> -->
                            <!-- <template if:true={shiptolist}> -->
                                <lightning-datatable
                                    key-field="id"
                                    data={shiptolist}
                                    columns={columns}
                                    class="shipToOwnersTable"
                                ></lightning-datatable>
                            <!-- </template> -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-text-align_center">
                            <lightning-button 
                                variant="brand" 
                                label="Update Ownership" 
                                title="Primary action" 
                                onclick={updateCustomerAccountOwner}
                            ></lightning-button>
                        </div>
                    </div>




                    <!-- <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                        <div class="slds-size_1-of-3">
                            <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name='Account'>
                                <lightning-input-field field-name='User__c' onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input-field>
                            </lightning-record-edit-form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-size_1-of-3" style="margin-top: 2em;">
                            <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Update Ownership" title="Primary action"
                                onclick={updateCustomerAccountOwner}></lightning-button>
                        </div>
                    </div> -->
                  <!--  <slot> -->
                    <!-- <template if:true={shipToOwnerUniqueList}>
                        <lightning-card >
                                <lightning-datatable
                                            class='shipToOwnerTbl'
                                            key-field="OwnerId"
                                            data={shipToOwnerUniqueList}
                                            show-row-number-column
                                            columns={shipToOwners}
                                            onrowselection={handleRowSelection}
                                            max-row-selection=1
                                >
                                </lightning-datatable>
                        </lightning-card>
                    </template> -->
                    <!-- <template if:false={shipToOwnerUniqueList}>
                         <p class="slds-var-m-top_x-small modal-hidden">
                            <slot name="tagline"  >
                                This Account Does Not Have Any Related Ship-To Records
                            </slot>
                        </p>
                     </template>
                    <template if:true={shiptolist}>
                        <lightning-datatable
                                    key-field="id"
                                    data={shiptolist}
                                    show-row-number-column
                                    columns={columns}
                                    selected-rows={shipToSelected}
                            >
                            </lightning-datatable>

                    </template> -->
                    <!-- <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Update Ownership" title="Primary action" onclick={updateCustomerAccountOwner}>
                    </lightning-button> -->
                    <!-- </slot> -->
                </div>
                <footer class="slds-modal__footer modal-hidden">
                    <!-- <slot name="footer" ></slot> -->
                    <slot name="footer" onslotchange={handleSlotFooterChange} ></slot>

                </footer>
            </div>

        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    </template>
</template>
```

.js

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import getRelatedShipToList from '@salesforce/apex/CustomerAccountShipToController.getRelatedShipToList';
import updateCustomerAccountOwner from '@salesforce/apex/CustomerAccountShipToController.updateCustomerAccountOwner';
import { getRecordNotifyChange } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

const CSS_CLASS = 'modal-hidden';
const columns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Account_Id__c' },
    { label: 'Ship To Account', fieldName: 'Ship_To_Account__c', type: 'url',
        typeAttributes: { label: {fieldName:'Name'}, value: {fieldName:'Id'}, target: "_blank"}
    },
    { label: 'Ship To Owner', fieldName: 'ShipToOwnerName', type: 'text' },
    {
        label: 'City - State', fieldName: 'CityStateCombo', type: 'text'
    }
];
const customerColumns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Account_Id__c' },
    { label: 'Customer Account', fieldName: 'Ship_To_Account__c', type: 'url',
        typeAttributes: { label: {fieldName:'Name'}, value: {fieldName:'Id'}, target: "_blank"}
    },
    { label: 'Customer Account Owner', fieldName: 'ShipToOwnerName', type: 'text' },
    {
        label: 'City - State', fieldName: 'CityStateCombo', type: 'text'
    }
];
const shipToOwners = [
    { label: 'Change Customer Owner To:', fieldName: 'ShipToOwnerName', type: 'text' },
];

export default class ModalBox extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track data;
    @track customerAccountData;
    @track error;
    @track columns = columns;
    @track customerColumns = customerColumns;
    @track shipToOwners = shipToOwners;

    @track selectedOwner;
    @track selectedOwnerId;
    @track shiptolist;
    @track customerAccountlist;
    @api showModal;
    @track shipToOwnerUniqueList = [];
    @track selectedOwner = [];
    @api value;
    @api required = false;

    @track shipToSelected;

    @track lookupValue;
    @track currentShipToOwnersSelected;

    @wire(getRelatedShipToList, { customerAccountId: '$recordId' })
    wiredInitData({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
           console.log("modalBox|wiredInitData|data  =  " + JSON.stringify(data));

            this.data = data.shipTos;
            this.customerAccountData = data.customerAccount;
        } else if (error) {
            console.log("modalBox|wiredInitData|error  =  " + JSON.stringify(error));

            this.error = error;
        }
    }

    @api invoke() {
        console.log("modalBox|invoke|start");
        this.showModal = true;
        
        if (this.data !== undefined) {
            let arrayFlatObjs = [];
            const shipToOwnerSet = [];
            this.data.forEach(item => {
                const clonedItem = { ...item };
                const shipToOwnerName = String(item["Owner"].FirstName + " " + item["Owner"].LastName);
                clonedItem.CityStateCombo = String(item.ShippingCity) + ' - ' + String(item.ShippingState);
                clonedItem.ShipToOwnerName = shipToOwnerName;
                clonedItem.Ship_To_Account__c = '/lightning/r/Account/' + String(item.Id) + '/view';
                const shipToOwnerObj = {
                    OwnerId: item.OwnerId,
                    ShipToOwnerName: shipToOwnerName

                };
                if (shipToOwnerSet.filter(obj => obj.OwnerId === item.OwnerId).length === 0) {
                    shipToOwnerSet.push(shipToOwnerObj);
                };
                const flatObj = this.flattenJSON(clonedItem);
                arrayFlatObjs = [...arrayFlatObjs, flatObj];

            });
            this.shipToOwnerUniqueList = [...shipToOwnerSet];
            this.shiptolist = arrayFlatObjs
            console.log("modalBox|invoke|shiptolist  = " + JSON.stringify(this.shiptolist));
            console.log("modalBox|invoke|shipToOwnerUniqueList  = " + JSON.stringify(this.shipToOwnerUniqueList));
        }

        
        
        if (this.customerAccountData !== undefined) {
            let arrayFlatObjs = [];
            const shipToOwnerSet = [];


            const clonedItem = { ...this.customerAccountData };
            const shipToOwnerName = String(this.customerAccountData["Owner"].FirstName + " " + this.customerAccountData["Owner"].LastName);
            clonedItem.CityStateCombo = String(item.ShippingCity) + ' - ' + String(this.customerAccountData.ShippingState);
            clonedItem.ShipToOwnerName = shipToOwnerName;
            clonedItem.Ship_To_Account__c = '/lightning/r/Account/' + String(this.customerAccountData.Id) + '/view';
            const shipToOwnerObj = {
                OwnerId: this.customerAccountData.OwnerId,
                ShipToOwnerName: shipToOwnerName

            };
            if (shipToOwnerSet.filter(obj => obj.OwnerId === item.OwnerId).length === 0) {
                shipToOwnerSet.push(shipToOwnerObj);
            };
            const flatObj = this.flattenJSON(clonedItem);
            arrayFlatObjs = [...arrayFlatObjs, flatObj];
            this.customerAccountlist = arrayFlatObjs
            console.log("modalBox|invoke|shiptolist  = " + JSON.stringify(this.shiptolist));
            console.log("modalBox|invoke|shipToOwnerUniqueList  = " + JSON.stringify(this.shipToOwnerUniqueList));
        }

        // this.showModal = true;
    }

    flattenJSON(data) {
       console.log('modalBox|flattenJSON|start');

        let result = {};

        function recurse(cur, prop) {
            if (Object(cur) !== cur) {
                result[prop] = cur;
            }
            else if (Array.isArray(cur)) {
                for (var i = 0, l = cur.length; i < l; i++) {
                    recurse(cur[i], prop + "[" + i + "]");
                }

                if (l == 0) {
                    result[prop] = [];
                }
            }
            else {
                let isEmpty = true;
                for (let p in cur) {
                    isEmpty = false;
                    recurse(cur[p], prop ? prop + "." + p : p);
                }
                if (isEmpty && prop) {
                    result[prop] = {};
                }
            }
        }
        recurse(data, "");
        console.log('modalBox|flattenJSON|end');

        return result;
    }
   async updateCustomerAccountOwner() {  /// u[date] for updating/deleting record instead of insert
        try {
            var selectedRecords = this.template.querySelector("lightning-datatable.shipToOwnersTable").getSelectedRows();
            if (selectedRecords.length == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            var selectedShipToOwner = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable.shipToOwnerTbl').getSelectedRows();
            var selectedlookup = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-field.shipToOwnerLkup').value;
            if (selectedlookup == null && selectedShipToOwner == null) {
                return null;
            } else if (selectedlookup != null && (selectedShipToOwner == null || selectedShipToOwner.length == 0)) {
                this.selectedOwnerId = selectedlookup;
            } else if (selectedlookup == null && selectedShipToOwner != null) {
                this.selectedOwnerId = selectedShipToOwner[0].OwnerId;
            }
            if (this.selectedOwnerId == null || this.selectedOwnerId == "") {
                return;
            }
            const ownerIdToPass = this.selectedOwnerId;


            if (ownerIdToPass !== null) {
                await updateCustomerAccountOwner({ ownerId: String(ownerIdToPass), accountsToUpdate: selectedRecords })
                // updateCustomerAccountOwner({ ownerName: String(this.selectedOwner[0].Ship_to_Owner__c), customerAccountId: this.recordId })
                    .then((result) => {
                        // console.log('modalBox|updateCustomerAccountOwner|result: ' + result);
                        if (result === true) {
                            this.throwToastMessage('Success', 'The Customer Account Owner has been successfully updated!', 'success');
                            const closedialog = new CustomEvent('closedialog');
                            this.dispatchEvent(closedialog);
                            this.hide();
                            getRecordNotifyChange([{ recordId: this.recordId }]);
                            
                        } else {
                            // console.log('modalBox|updateCustomerAccountOwner|result: ' + result);
                            this.throwToastMessage('Error', 'Customer Account Was Not Updated. Updated = ' + result, 'error');
                        }
                    }).catch(error => {
                        const errMsg = 'Error updating Customer Account Owner:  ' + JSON.stringify(error.message);
                        this.throwToastMessage('Error', errMsg, 'error');
                    });
            } else {
                this.throwToastMessage('Error', 'You must select a row from the list of available Owners, or search for an Owner in the Input field.', 'error');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            this.throwToastMessage('Error', 'An Unexpected Error Occured. Error = ' + error, 'error');
        }

    }

    handleChange(event) {
        // console.log('modalBox|updateCustomerAccountOwner|handleChange|start|event.detail.value: ' + event.detail.value); handleRowSelection
        
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable.shipToOwnerTbl').getSelectedRows();
        this.selectedOwnerId = event.detail.value;
        // console.log('modalBox|updateCustomerAccountOwner|this.selectedOwnerId: ' + this.selectedOwnerId);
        // console.log('modalBox|updateCustomerAccountOwner|this.selectedOwnerId.length (before clear): ' + this.selectedOwner.length);
        this.selectedOwner = [];
        // console.log('modalBox|updateCustomerAccountOwner|this.selectedOwnerId.length (after clear): ' + this.selectedOwner.length);
        this.currentShipToOwnersSelected = [];
    }

    handleRowSelection(event) {
        // console.log('modalBox|updateCustomerAccountOwner|handleChange|start|event.detail.value: ' + event.detail.value); handleRowSelection
        // const selectedOwnerId = event.detail.selectedRows != null ? event.detail.selectedRows : [...this.selectedShipTos, event.detail.value];
        const selectedOwnerId = event.detail.selectedRows[0].OwnerId ;

      //   console.log('addUserToB2B|handleShipToChange|this.selectedShipTos: ' + JSON.stringify(this.selectedShipTos));
        this.selectedOwnerId = selectedOwnerId;
        console.log('modalBox|handleRowSelection|this.selectedOwnerId: ' + this.selectedOwnerId);
        // console.log('modalBox|updateCustomerAccountOwner|this.selectedOwnerId.length (before clear): ' + this.selectedOwner.length);
        // console.log('modalBox|updateCustomerAccountOwner|this.selectedOwnerId.length (after clear): ' + this.selectedOwner.length);
        this.lookupValue = null;
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-field.shipToOwnerLkup').value = null;
        
    }

    throwToastMessage(msgTitle, msg, type) {
    //console.log('qLekkerAdminUtils|throwToastMessage|start');
    dispatchEvent(
        new ShowToastEvent({
            title: msgTitle,
            message: msg,
            variant: type
        }));
    //console.log('qLekkerAdminUtils|throwToastMessage|end');

}

    @api
    set header(value) {
        this.hasHeaderString = value !== '';
        this._headerPrivate = value;
    }
    get header() {
        return this._headerPrivate;
    }

    hasHeaderString = false;
    _headerPrivate;

    @api show() {
        this.showModal = true;
    }

    @api hide() {
        this.showModal = false;
    }

    handleDialogClose() {
        //Let parent know that dialog is closed (mainly by that cross button) so it can set proper variables if needed
        const closedialog = new CustomEvent('closedialog');
        this.dispatchEvent(closedialog);
        this.hide();
    }

    handleSlotTaglineChange() {
        // Only needed in "show" state. If hiding, we're removing from DOM anyway
        // Added to address Issue #344 where querySelector would intermittently return null element on hide
        if (this.showModal === false) {
            return;
        }
        const taglineEl = this.template.querySelector('p');
        taglineEl.classList.remove(CSS_CLASS);
    }

    handleSlotFooterChange() {
        // Only needed in "show" state. If hiding, we're removing from DOM anyway
        // Added to address Issue #344 where querySelector would intermittently return null element on hide
        if (this.showModal === false) {
            return;
        }
        const footerEl = this.template.querySelector('footer');
        footerEl.classList.remove(CSS_CLASS);
    }
}
```

.cls

```
public with sharing class CustomerAccountShipToController {


    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
    public static Boolean updateCustomerAccountOwner(String ownerId, List<Account> accountsToUpdate) {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '***** ownerId = '+ownerId);
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '***** accountsToUpdate = '+accountsToUpdate);
        Boolean accountUpdated = false;
        try {
            for (Account acct : accountsToUpdate) {
                acct.OwnerId = ownerId;
                acct.Customer_Owner_Needs_Review__c = false;
                acct.Need_Owner_Update__c = false;
                acct.Bypass_Validation__c = true;
            }
            // turn off validation rule for Customer Accounts before updating account
            Account_Automation_Settings__c accCustomSetting = [SELECT Id, Validation_Rules_Enabled__c, Run_Trigger__c FROM Account_Automation_Settings__c ];
            accCustomSetting.Validation_Rules_Enabled__c = false;
            update accCustomSetting;
            update accountsToUpdate;
            // turn back on after update
            accCustomSetting.Validation_Rules_Enabled__c = true;
            update accCustomSetting;

            accountUpdated = true;
            LTMAccountUpdateBatchHelper.skipTriggers = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('CustomerAccountShipToController|updateCustomerAccountOwner|Exception:  ' + e.getLineNumber() + ' | ' + e.getCause() + ' | ' + e.getMessage());
        }
        return accountUpdated;
    }

    public class accountWrapper {
        @AuraEnabled
        public List<Account> shipTos {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled 
        public Account customerAccount {get; set;}
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static accountWrapper getRelatedShipToList(String customerAccountId) {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '***** customerAccountId = '+customerAccountId);
        User integrationUser = [SELECT Id FROM User  WHERE Profile.Name='Integration Profile'  AND IsActive=true  AND Name='Integration User' LIMIT 1];
        User corpAccountsUser = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE IsActive=true AND Name='Corporate Accounts'];
        List<Id> ownersToExclude = new List<Id>{integrationUser.Id, corpAccountsUser.Id};
        Id s2AccRTID = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Ship To').getRecordTypeId();

        List<Account> shipToList = [ SELECT ID, Name, ParentId, 
                                            Ship2_Delivery_Type__c, ShippingCity, 
                                            ShippingState, Parent.ShippingCity, Parent.ShippingState, 
                                            Parent.Name, OwnerId, Account_Id__c, CreatedDate, 
                                            Owner.FirstName, Owner.LastName,
                                            LT_Commission_GP_Ship_To_Account__c, ERP_Deleted_Text__c
                                        FROM Account
                                        WHERE ParentId=:customerAccountId
                                        AND (LT_Commission_GP_Ship_To_Account__c > 0.0 OR createdDate >=last_n_months:6)
                                        // AND Ship2_Delivery_Type__c = 'Lube'
                                        AND OwnerId NOT IN:ownersToExclude
                                        AND Owner.IsActive = true
                                        AND ERP_Deleted_Text__c != 'Deleted'
                                        AND RecordTypeId=:s2AccRTID
                                        WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
                                    ];
        List<Account> shipToListLube = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> shipToListNoLube= new List<Account>();

        for (Account shipTo : shipToList) {
            if (shipTo.Ship2_Delivery_Type__c == 'Lube') {
                shipToListLube.add(shipTo);
            } else {
                shipToListNoLube.add(shipTo);
            }
        }
        // include non-lube shipto's if all ship-to's are non-lube, otherwise exclude non-lube
        List<Account> shipToListToReturn = shipToListNoLube.size() == shipToList.size() ? shipToListNoLube : shipToListLube;

        accountWrapper acctWrap = new accountWrapper();
        acctWrap.shipTos = shipToListToReturn;
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '***** acctWrap = '+acctWrap);
        Account customerAccount;
        try {
            customerAccount = [
                SELECT
                    ID, 
                    Name, 
                    ParentId, 
                    Ship2_Delivery_Type__c, 
                    ShippingCity, 
                    ShippingState, 
                    Parent.ShippingCity, 
                    Parent.ShippingState, 
                    Parent.Name, 
                    OwnerId, 
                    Account_Id__c, 
                    CreatedDate, 
                    Owner.FirstName, 
                    Owner.LastName,
                    LT_Commission_GP_Ship_To_Account__c, 
                    ERP_Deleted_Text__c
                FROM
                    Account
                WHERE
                    Id = :customerAccountId
            ];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            system.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '***** e.getMessage() = '+e.getMessage());
            system.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '***** e.getStackTraceString() = '+e.getStackTraceString());
        }
        acctWrap.customerAccount = customerAccount;
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '***** acctWrap = '+acctWrap);
        return acctWrap;
    }

}
```

Comment: if the class isn't being called, recordId is probably undefined. what's calling this LWC? is it passing in the recordId?

Comment: Check console for any errors and also try with [debug mode enabled](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.aura_debug_mode.htm&type=5).

Comment: Do you have your Apex class in the Profile / Permissionset's Apex Class Access section ?